# Counter Strike Source problem with wine

Tags: wine

When I tried to run CS Source via wine I  got the following error

```
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33e224,0x00000000), stub!
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 240
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198340082888 [API loaded no]
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:keyboard:X11DRV_LoadKeyboardLayout L"00000409", 0000: semi-stub! Returning default layout.
fixme:xinput:XInputGetCapabilities (index 0, flags 0x1, capabilities 0x33e634) Stub!
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0xf4cff82c, 0x181c90, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0xf4cff82c
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33d9a4,0x00000000), stub!
Using breakpad crash handler
fixme:d3d9:D3DPERF_SetOptions (0x1) : stub
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x5a574152 (as fourcc: RAWZ) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x5a574152) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
fixme:dbghelp:MiniDumpWriteDump NIY MiniDumpWithHandleData
err:ole:RevokeDragDrop invalid hwnd (nil)
fixme:avifile:AVIFileExit (): stub!
```

[When I ran the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDSqn.png)
[The game exited and gave me a messed up screen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVS6k.png)
Do you know how to solve it??
If yes please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The `fixme:` messages from `wine` indicates a part of `wine` that the developers of `wine` haven't written yet. Rather than aborting, they issue the message, and continue.

What this means is that "Counter Strike Source" will NOT run with the current version of `wine`.

Comment: But counter strike source is in platinum list of wine.

Comment: Indeed it is: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3731 (for Wine versions 1.9.10 and 2.12).

Comment: I am on Wine 2.21.What might be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here follows another answer to this topic. Yes, I am aware that the original question was asked quite some time ago. But there exist in the meantime two interesting alternatives to resolve those `fourcc: DF16` and `fourcc: DF24` errors in old D3D9 based games.

The solution is to use [**Gallium Nine**](https://github.com/iXit/wine-nine-standalone) or **DXVK** instead of WineD3D.

In my case I had the following error output at the CLI when WineD3D was used. After installing Gallium Nine all of them were resolved and the graphics looks clearly better and the game runs faster.

```
0024:err:d3d:wined3d_unregister_window Window 0002005E is not registered with wined3d.
0024:fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
0024:fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table.
0024:fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
0024:fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table.
```

Note, this was tested with the GOG version of the iconic platformer game [Rayman 2: The Great Escape](https://www.gog.com/de/game/rayman_2_the_great_escape) in conjunction with the [nGlide wrapper](https://www.zeus-software.com/downloads/nglide) which translates Glide to D3D9.